# Mask elements of a list that are words, and convert the rest to integers in python

Tags: string, list, integer, masking

Let's say I have a list of lists, where one of the lists within this big list looks like this:

['blabblah1234', '2013-08-23T22:52:08.060', '56527.9529', '56527.9544', '109.7147', '0.0089', '14.3638', '0.0779', '14.3136', '0.0775', '14.3305', '0.1049', '14.3628', '0.0837', '14.3628', '0.0837', '70.9990', '40.0050', '173.046', '-30.328', '73', '-99.175', '0.000', '0.000', '59.8', '0.0', '1.0']

My question is, how can I mask the first two terms: blablah1234 and 2013-08-23whatever and after that work only with the other elements by converting them into integers (that is, getting rid of the quotes, so that I can do computation with those numbers later?)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert any strings you can to float. Anything that can't be converted will just be skipped.

```
other_list = ()
for elem in your_list:
    try:
       val = float(elem)
       new_list.append(val)
    except ValueError:
       pass
```

Comment: I've masked elements in my list, I have this so far: with f2 being my super huge list containing tiny lists:fnew = ma.array(f2[1])
>>> fnew[0] = ma.masked
>>> fnew[1] = ma.masked

Comment: my output came out list this:>>> fnew
masked_array(data = [-- -- '56527.9529' '56527.9544' '109.7147' '0.0089' '14.3638' '0.0779'
 '14.3136' '0.0775' '14.3305' '0.1049' '14.3628' '0.0837' '14.3628'
 '0.0837' '70.9990' '40.0050' '173.046' '-30.328' '73' '-99.175' '0.000'
 '0.000' '59.8' '0.0' '1.0'],
             mask = [ True  True False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False],
       fill_value = N/A)

Comment: so basically next step I want to get rid of the quotes from the other elements and make them into integers but i don't know how to, the map(int,my_list) thing doesn't work!